# Change array elements to objects with key, value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

Can anyone tell me how to change this array in javaScript to the following one with objects having the same key 'name' ?

```
const myArray = ['mark', 'david', 'monica'];
```

Desired Output:

```
const myArray = [{name: 'mark'}, {name: 'david'}, {name: 'monica'}];
```

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const myArray = ['mark', 'david', 'monica'];
const result = myArray.map(i => ({
  name: i
}));
console.log(result);
```